# Template validation error: Role arn:aws:iam is invalid or cannot be assumed

Tags: docker, amazon-iam

I am using [this cloudformation template](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home#/stacks/new?stackName=Docker&templateURL=https://editions-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/aws/stable/Docker.tmpl) on the [docker website](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/#docker-community-edition-ce-for-aws) to create a `docker-for-aws` stack.

I am getting this error, however:

```
Template validation error: Role arn:aws:iam::1234567890:
role/docker-for-aws-role is invalid or cannot be assumed
```

[image]

I assigned a role because the IAM user I am using does not have IAM creation right.

The custom policy of the role **arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/docker-for-aws-role** follows the text here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/iam-permissions/, and I reproduce it here as a reference:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1481924239005",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CancelUpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:ContinueUpdateRollback",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateUploadBucket",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeAccountLimits",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:EstimateTemplateCost",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:GetStackPolicy",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary",
                "cloudformation:ListChangeSets",
                "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
                "cloudformation:ListStacks",
                "cloudformation:PreviewStackUpdate",
                "cloudformation:SetStackPolicy",
                "cloudformation:SignalResource",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1481924344000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AllocateHosts",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:AssociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:AttachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateNatGateway",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateRoute",
                "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateSubnet",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:CreateVolume",
                "ec2:CreateVpc",
                "ec2:DeleteInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteNatGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteRouteTable",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteSubnet",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DeleteVolume",
                "ec2:DeleteVpc",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeHosts",
                "ec2:DescribeImageAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeRegions",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DetachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DetachVolume",
                "ec2:DisassociateAddress",
                "ec2:DisassociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:GetConsoleOutput",
                "ec2:GetConsoleScreenshot",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:ReleaseAddress",
                "ec2:ReleaseHosts",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1481924651000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:AttachInstances",
                "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancers",
                "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
                "autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:CreateLaunchConfiguration",
                "autoscaling:CreateOrUpdateTags",
                "autoscaling:DeleteAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:DeleteLaunchConfiguration",
                "autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook",
                "autoscaling:DeleteNotificationConfiguration",
                "autoscaling:DeletePolicy",
                "autoscaling:DeleteScheduledAction",
                "autoscaling:DeleteTags",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAccountLimits",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingNotificationTypes",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLaunchConfigurations",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHookTypes",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
                "autoscaling:DescribeTags",
                "autoscaling:DetachInstances",
                "autoscaling:DetachLoadBalancers",
                "autoscaling:DisableMetricsCollection",
                "autoscaling:EnableMetricsCollection",
                "autoscaling:EnterStandby",
                "autoscaling:ExecutePolicy",
                "autoscaling:ExitStandby",
                "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
                "autoscaling:PutNotificationConfiguration",
                "autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "autoscaling:PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction",
                "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat",
                "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
                "autoscaling:SetDesiredCapacity",
                "autoscaling:SetInstanceHealth",
                "autoscaling:SetInstanceProtection",
                "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
                "autoscaling:TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1481924759004",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteTable",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:ListTables",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateTable"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1481924854000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DeleteLogGroup",
                "logs:DeleteLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1481924989003",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
                "sqs:CreateQueue",
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:DeleteQueue",
                "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
                "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
                "sqs:ListQueues",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:SetQueueAttributes"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1481924989002",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1481924989001",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ApplySecurityGroupsToLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:AttachLoadBalancerToSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ConfigureHealthCheck",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancerListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancerPolicy",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancerListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancerPolicy",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeInstanceHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerPolicyTypes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DetachLoadBalancerFromSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DisableAvailabilityZonesForLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:EnableAvailabilityZonesForLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetLoadBalancerListenerSSLCertificate",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetLoadBalancerPoliciesForBackendServer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetLoadBalancerPoliciesOfListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetRulePriorities",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1487169681000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1487169681009",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the screen shot of the role

[image]

**Question:** what did I miss out when I create the role?

Comment: Hopefully you've resolved the issue by now. The IAM Role you're creating has to be for CloudFormation, not EC2 [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQtdm.png) After you've selected it, add the required policies